# Bootstrap 3: How to pad columns in a row when the number of columns is unknown?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLzah1x4/4/) for full code example.

I couldn't figure out how to upload my `placeholder.png` image. Nevertheless, notice that there are (supposed to be) 6 images under the subheading?

When I run this locally (where my browser can actually resolve `placeholder.png`) the images are all smushed together. I can force them to be separated by hackishly adding `&nbsp;`'s but that seems like the wrong way to accomplish padding:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <img src="placeholder.png"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="placeholder.png"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="placeholder.png"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="placeholder.png"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="placeholder.png"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <img src="placeholder.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Any ideas how I can get these to be padded such that all 6 images are centered and yet still take up most of the page width?**

Also, just to throw a curve ball into the equation, when this runs in production, the server decides how many images to send back. It won't always be 6 images: it will *always* be between 3 and 7 images (so: 3, 4, 5, 6 ot 7 images). I need this to be smart enough to center the images and make them take up most of the page width *regardless* of how many images are returned by the server. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need some basic javascript for this to work. Is that an option for you?

Comment: jQuery yes, but I'm curious as to why there wouldn't be a Bootstrap/CSS solution...

Comment: Your input will vary, so you need variables to handle that unknown value. There are edge cases where css can be used to handle this sort of thing, but I doubt you'll find a css only solution to fit your particular needs. If there was a built in solution for this in bootstrap, it would be a javascript plugin.

Comment: **Hint**: to get sharable sample pictures when sharing your code online, use [placehold.it](http://placehold.it/) or [lorempixel.com](http://lorempixel.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Bootstrap's `list-inline`..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user secondary" style="display: block"></span>
        <span class="strong-primary">Who's using Fizz<b>Cloud</b>?</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></li>
        <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></li>
        <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></li>
        <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></li>
        <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></li>
        <li><img src="//placehold.it/100x100"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/DSpNtxqsYJ

Comment: It needs to take up most of the page width regardless of the number of images, per the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Skelly (+1) - in your demo, where/how are you importing the `placehold.it` lib?

Comment: @smeeb, placehold.it isn't a library, it's a image hosting site that just specializes in making non descript images where the content isn't important.  You can use it just like any other image url in your src tag when sharing code.

Comment: Thanks @KyleMit (+1) - but is it something that would just automagically work locally on my machine? If so, can I assume that my browser knows to call it by default?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Bootstrap Rows and Columns for this. I would actually use a Bootstrap Table (which I'll likely get yelled at for saying)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user secondary" style="display: block"></span>
                <span class="strong-primary">Who's using Fizz<b>Cloud</b>?</span>
            </h1>
         </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img-thumbnail"></td> 
            <td class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
            <td class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
            <td class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
            <td class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
            <td class="text-center"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img-thumbnail"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Visual: http://www.bootply.com/dmrb3J8ihl

This will also address the issue of having 3 - 7 pictures; the `table-responsive` class makes the table adjust to the width of your browser.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 My first reaction was to not like it because it uses a table.  And I'm still not crazy about the semantics of it, but it does solve the issue without any javascript.  Also, you can just apply `.text-center` to the table instead of adding it to every `td` element.

Comment: I know right? I hate tables too, but sometimes they just work. As for `.text-center` I wasn't aware that would work. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take up the full screen, you'll need each image to take up it's share of the available screen width.  I can't really see a way of doing this without jQuery.  The good news is, it's rather trivially implemented.

Just find the number of images.  Take the total percent width available and divide by that number.  Then apply that as a width to each image:

```js
var $images = $(".centerImages > img");
var numberImages = $images.length;
var width = 90/numberImages;
$images.css('width', width+'%');
```

```css
.centerImages {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="centerImages">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```